# System check identified 3 issues (0 silenced)

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, fedora-25

what could the issue with my model.py .i have tried everything nothing happens.and i think i defined my foreign key the right way .could it be a problem with my defining or do i have to use `memberid.user` in my foreginkey or what would be effect.any contribution is welcomed.

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f6a926d69b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 405, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
tithe.tithe.memberid: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'memberid', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
tithe.tithe.memberid: (fields.E307) The field tithe.tithe.memberid was declared with a lazy reference to 'tithe.memberid', but app 'tithe' doesn't provide model 'memberid'.
tithe.tithe: (models.E012) 'unique_together' refers to the non-existent field 'IntegerField'.

System check identified 3 issues (0 silenced).
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f3d3ccdc9b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 405, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
tithe.tithe.memberid: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
tithe.tithe.memberid: (fields.E307) The field tithe.tithe.memberid was declared with a lazy reference to 'tithe.user', but app 'tithe' doesn't provide model 'user'.
tithe.tithe: (models.E012) 'unique_together' refers to the non-existent field 'IntegerField'.
```

this my model.py code

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class tithe(models.Model):
    memberid = models.ForeignKey('User')
    membername = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    receitcode = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    tithes = models.IntegerField()
    combinedoffering = models.IntegerField()
    campmeetingoffering = models.IntegerField()
    churchbuilding = models.IntegerField()
    conference = models.IntegerField()
    localchurch = models.IntegerField()
    funds = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.receitcode

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["receitcode","IntegerField"]
        ordering = ["published_date","membername"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two warnings are because Django cannot find the model `'User'` that you refer to in the `memberid` foreign key.

I recommend you use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to reference the user model. This will work whether or not you have a custom user model.

```
memberid = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

See the docs for more info on [referencing the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Note that it would be better to call name your field `member`. That way, the related instance will be `member` and the related id will be `member_id`. At the moment, the related instance is `memberid`, and the related id is `memberid_id`.

The final warning is because you do not have a field `IntegerField` in the model. If you want the `receitcode` field to be unique by itself, then remove the `unique_together` line and change the field to:

```
receitcode = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
```

Comment: since i want the receipt to have a unique code i have chosen it to be `unique_together = ["receipt_code"]`

Comment: i have changed `memberid` to `member_id` and `membername` to be `member`i think this make sense now

Comment: You don't need `unique_together` to make a single field unique. Just use the `unique` option on the field.

Comment: You've misunderstood my point about foreign  keys. The foreign key should not contain `id`. See the note in the docs about [database representation](docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

Comment: is that why i am not able to migrate .`No changes detected in app 'tithe'
`

Comment: i have changed from `member_id` to `member_code` `member_code = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)` plus i have changed to `receitcode = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)`

Comment: i a have one problem i am not able to make migration .when i write this command in my terminal nothing is migrated `python manage.py makemigrations tithe`what could be the issue.

Comment: Make sure that `tithe` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: tithe is on my installed app i hard intergrated wagitail  in my system to help in content management can that cause that issue

Comment: check my new model.py it does not have any error but migration does not take place

Comment: Remove `abstract = True`. If you still have problems, please ask a new question since your original question has been solved.

Comment: this is  [link to my new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649283/no-changes-detected-when-i-excute-pyhon-manage-py-makemigrations-and-migrate?noredirect=1#comment78257937_45649283)

Answer (score 2):

The line below

```
memberid = models.ForeignKey('User')
```

is causing the problem. You have to pass a User object to it.

Import `User` model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

then

```
memberid = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: can i change to `memberid - models.ForeignKey('memberid.User')`

Comment: memberid.User won't work. memberid does not have any attribute named User. Default User model will work here. Also you don't have to pass it as string.

Answer (score -1):

Your ForeignKey needs to reference a concrete model or abstract model. Since you are referencing using a string (which means the model is abstract) you need to declare the class Meta: as abstract by stating abstract = True

Relationships defined this way on abstract models are resolved when the model is subclassed as a concrete model and are not relative to the abstract model’s app_label:

The below information is from the Django Documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/

```
 products/models.py
from django.db import models

class AbstractCar(models.Model):
manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# This is what you need to add
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```