# No changes detected when i excute Python manage.py makemigrations and migrate

Tags: python, django, postgresql, fedora-25

I tried to make migration using `python manage.py migrations tithe` but nothing is detected. I have even changed my database to postgres, but nothing has changed. Even `python manage.py migrate` is not working. What could be the problem?

```
@localhost church]$ python manage.py migrate tithe
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: (none)
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

this is my model.py code

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.signals import setting_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class tithe(models.Model):
    member_code = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    member = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    receipt_code = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    tithes = models.IntegerField()
    combinedoffering = models.IntegerField()
    campmeetingoffering = models.IntegerField()
    churchbuilding = models.IntegerField()
    conference = models.IntegerField()
    localchurch = models.IntegerField()
    funds = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.receitcode

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: in your app there is a folder migrations delete that folder and then try it

Comment: `CommandError: App 'tithe' does not have migrations.` after deleting it give this error message

Comment: @rahul.m did you seriously suggest to delete the entire migrations folder? Why would you do that? How about deleting one or two migrations and try it again, but the entire folder?

Comment: Try running python manage.py makemigrations tithe then running python manage.py migrate tithe

Comment: I never deleted  I just  removed the entire  folder from the project  .should  delete int.py from migration  folder or what exactly should I remove   .I have  two files  inside that folder

Comment: still the same  error after removing `__init__.py` `CommandError: App 'tithe' does not have migrations`

Comment: Add the debugging info to your post, output of `echo $PYTHONPATH`, `pwd`, `tree -L 2`,`echo $PATH`

Comment: Already  working  after removing  abstract  in class meta

Answer (score 0):

the program works by removing `abstract = True`in the class meta.after removing it when i run `python manage.py makemigrations tithe` and `python manage.py migrate tithe` it works wells

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.signals import setting_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class tithe(models.Model):
    member_code = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    member = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    receipt_code = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    tithes = models.IntegerField()
    combinedoffering = models.IntegerField()
    campmeetingoffering = models.IntegerField()
    churchbuilding = models.IntegerField()
    conference = models.IntegerField()
    localchurch = models.IntegerField()
    funds = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.receitcode

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["receipt_code"]
```